# How to convert Future<StreamedResponse> to Future<Response>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to send a DELETE request with body, but `http.delete` doesn't support adding a body to the request.

I've found this solution online but I want to return `Response` rather than `StreamedResponse`. How can I achieve that?

```
  static Future<http.Response> deleteFavorites({Map<String, int> body}) async {
    UserRepository userRepository = UserRepository();
    String token = await userRepository.storage.read(key: 'token');
    final client = http.Client();
    var response;
    try {
      response =
          await client.send(http.Request("DELETE", Uri.parse(favoritesUrl))
            ..headers["access-token"] = token
            ..body = jsonEncode(body));
      //
    } finally {
      client.close();
    }
    return response;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the static method in Response class fromStream , that take StreamedResponse and return the Future that you want, just change the return to :

```
return Response.fromStream(response);
```

You can check the docs https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Response-class.html .

Hope it helps!